# Why my cells do not load at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uitableview, asynchronous

I'm using background thread for getting my data from the network and main thread for presenting my cells:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), {
    let _ = self.http.getInfo() { (result) in
        self.cellsArray = result

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        completion(completed: true)
    }
})
```

where `self.http.getInfo` is a `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest` method for taking my network infos.

And when I run my app my cells start showing separately as: the first appears, in a second the next one appears, in 2 seconds the next one and etc.

Why they do not appear at the same time? And also, because of the background and main thread using, my UITableView jumps when I implement infinite scroll and append new cells to exist cell array.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

write `self.tableView.reloadData()` this statement in completion handler of `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest`.

Comment: but how can I update my tableView from another file?

Comment: I have 2 files: Network and UITableViewController. In my Network file I do my `dataTaskWithRequest` and display it in my UITableViewController. I've tried to reload my tableView from the network file via NSNotificationCenter, but it's still buggy and jumps

Comment: I have added it like this `completion(result: topNews)
                                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refreshMyTableView", object: nil)`